# Is there another verb for "stitch someone up"? What is the American alternative for this verb?

Tags: word-request, synonyms, dialect

Stitch someone up as in he is gonna stitch her up for the murder.

Here is an entry from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> [stitch sb up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stitch-sb-up)
>   UK slang
>   — phrasal verb with stitch uk ​ /stɪtʃ/ us ​ /stɪtʃ/ verb
>
> - to deliberately make someone look guilty of doing something that they did not do:
>     *He claims he was stitched up by the police.*

Is there any verb that can be used in this context? Since this phrasal verb is only used in the UK, what is its American counterpart?

Answer (score 4):

> [frame](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/frame) verb [ T ] (MAKE GUILTY)
>   ​infml to make a person seem to be guilty of a crime by providing false  information:
>   It looked like somebody was trying to frame him.
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

*Example*: The accused man said that he had been framed.

or

> [set up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/set-up)
>   6. phrasal verb
>   If you are set up by someone, they make it seem that you have done something wrong when you have not.
>   [informal]
>   He claimed yesterday that he had been set up after drugs were discovered at his home.
>   (Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Although it's not required, I think it's especially helpful if you could provide some entries from reputable sources. Also, please [cite your sources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) if you do use any. Otherwise, it might be considered plagiarism.